# flask - How to display a selected dropdown value in same html page?

Tags: python, flask

I am developing a flask application, in which I have a dropdown, when I select an option, it should display below the dropdown "Your selected score : " and the selected score.

I am displaying a dropdown like below :

```html
<select name="score">
    {% for score in range(6) %}
    <option value={{score}}> {{score}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I am displying thr selected value like :

`Your selected score : {{ score }}`

I tried and search a lot couldn't find anything. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: The user selection event is fired on the browser side so you need js event handler that do what you want.

Comment: @balderman, I was wondering if we can achieve this without js?

Comment: As you can in the answers, js handler is the  direction you need to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) fired on select element.

Try,

```
<select name="score" onchange="updateSelected(event)">
    {% for score in range(6) %}
    <option value={{score}}> {{score}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<div id="res"></>

<script>
    function updateSelected(event) {
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = 'Your selected score : ' + event.target.value;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').on('change', function(){
        $('#result').html('Your score is: ' + $(this).find('option:selected').val());
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <select name="score">
    {% for score in range(6) %}
    <option value="{{score}}">{{score}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```