# Updating the same site with Python's Flask module

Tags: python, flask

**Background:**

I'm fairly new to developing front end and the Flask module in Python. I am difficulty updating the same page.

**What I want to achieve:**

There are three parts to what I want to achieve

**Part/Step 1:** I can create a form such as the one below

[image]

**Part/Step 2:** When the form is filled in as below, and the [verify] button is hit it goes to *Step 3*
[image]

**Part/Step 3:** Once the verify button is hit, just underneath it the information that was passed gets placed underneath it. There are also two buttons, with [commit] and [cancel] button. If [cancel] is hit, the site resets to as it were in *Step 1*. If [commit] is hit, it goes to a different website in *step 4*

[image]

**Part/Step 4:** If [commit] is hit from the image above, another site is retrieved with the following message.

[image]

**Note:**

Happy to share my code, but I just have the empty form in step 1. I can't proceed after that. As mentioned, I'm very new to front end stuff.

---

**Update:**
I'm having difficulties with 2 things currently:

1. When I click [cancel], the whole form shifts to the left (*How can I make it centered?*)
2. How can I print multiple things (ideally in a centered table) after hitting the [verify] button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("committed").style.display = "none"; 
    })
    function onVerify() {
        document.getElementById("verifyName").innerHTML = 'First Name: ' + document.getElementById("first_name").value
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "block"; 
    }
    function onCommit() {
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("committed").style.display = "block"; 
    }
    function onCancel() {
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("name").value = ""
    }
</script>


    <style>
        h3 {text-align: center;}
        .right {
            text-align: right;
            margin-right: 1em;
            }
        .center {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            }
    </style>

</head>

<h3>Personnel Details</h3>
<div class="center" id="form">
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">
       <label>Salutation:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="gender">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="male">Mr.</option>
          <option value="female">Ms.</option>                    
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">
       <label>First Name:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
       <input id="first_name">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">
       <label>Middle Name:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input id="middle_name">
      </td>    
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">
       <label>Last Name:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input id="last_name">
      </td>    
 </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="right">
       <label>Email:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input id="email">
      </td>    
 </tr>    <tr>
      <td class="right">
       <label>DOB:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="date" name="issue_date" value="" min="1900-01-01" max="2100-12-31">
      </td>    
 </tr>    
    
    <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
      <td  class="center">
        <div>
            <button onclick="onVerify()">Verify</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    
    
    </table>
</div>
<div id="verify">
    <div id="verifyName">
    </div>
    <button onclick="onCommit()">Commit</button>
    <button onclick="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div id="committed">
    Committed! :)
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a Flask problem. What you want sounds like a single page application and you would need JavaScript to achieve this. Basically you need to bind a method to your `Verify` button, and when it is clicked, the method sends a POST request to Flask and Flask will send back a JSON response to the frontend, where it will then update the page with the JSON results. The `Commit` and `Cancel` buttons would also have to be implemented with JS. Flask has an example for writing functions that respond with JSON [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/jquery/#json-view-functions)

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58419526/6635464) helpful? It's more like JavaScript  changes you require to do this.

Comment: @ngShravil.py I'm really struggling :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the minimal code, I have used to just give an idea, how to achieve the similar behavior, with just one input field. You can easily extend this with other fields.

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("committed").style.display = "none"; 
    })
    function onVerify() {
        document.getElementById("verifyName").innerHTML = 'First Name: ' + document.getElementById("name").value
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "block"; 
    }
    function onCommit() {
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none"; 
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("committed").style.display = "block"; 
    }
    function onCancel() {
        document.getElementById("form").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("verify").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("name").value = ""
    }
</script>
<div id="form">
    <label> First Name:
        <input id="name">
    </label>
    <div>
        <button onclick="onVerify()">Veryfy</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="verify">
    <div id="verifyName">
    </div>
    <button onclick="onCommit()">Commit</button>
    <button onclick="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
<div id="committed">
    Committed! :)
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but I'm still struggling - I've appended "update" to my question.. I can't seem to get rid of this 2 issues! :(

Comment: Your code is working fine in my browser. In which browser are you checking?

Comment: Two issues are still there :/ Despite changing the CDN